Hibernate mode with Cinnamon
I have a set of 5 monitors with my Ubuntu 24.10 system and I am in use of the Cinnamon desktop. When entering the hibernate mode (the mode that kind-of turns the computer off), and then re-enter the system, all the desktop settings are lost. The monitor set is now in one line, all next to each other, and does not comply anymore with my previous set. Restarting the system puts every monitor again where it belongs to, but this is hardly a solution.
Is this a known bug? What is the reason for this to happen? Is there a solution for it?
